# Modifying "Multiple Ring Buffer" Magnitude based on value of input point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I'm trying to visualize the area of influence around an earthquake epicenter based on Magnitude.

Is there a way to modify the multiple ring buffer function so that it's not just a given distance away from the epicenter?